# Why cloned struct value still equals to the original struct

Tags: go, reference, pass-by-value

I created the following interface:

```
type cloneable interface {
    clone() cloneable
}
```

And a `person` struct (implements `cloneable`):

```
type person struct {
    firstName string
    lastName  string
    age       int
}

func (p person) clone() person {
    return person{p.firstName, p.lastName, p.age}
}
```

Now I attempt to clone my person value like so:

```
p1 := person{"name", "last", 22}
p2 := p1.clone()

fmt.Println(p2 == p1) // PRINTS 'true', why?
```

The clone method works as intended, but why p2 equals to p1? these are both values, not references, how can they be equal?

Comment: As you said, `p1` and `p2` are both values. Why are you expecting a comparison to check the memory address of the object? You can do that by using `&`.

Comment: There are no references in Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two structs will be equal if first, all their field types are `comparable` and all the corresponding field values are `equal`.

if your struct has at least one `function` or one uncomparable value, then you can not compare two structs

Answer (score 0):

From `The Go Programming Language Specification`:

> The equality operators **==** and **!=** apply to operands that are *comparable*. **...** These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:

[The Go Programming Language Specification: **Comparison operators**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)